# Spring JPA repository can save but after findBy throws "table not found" error

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

I have a Spring Boot Test like so :

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@Transactional
public class MyIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    ...

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        // Mockito mocks
        User u = new User();
        u.setName("test");
        userRepository.save(u);
    }

    @Test
    void myTest() {
        mockMvc.call to controller
    }
}
```

I added the `@Transactional` to the test class because otherwise the `save()` would fail in the `init()` method.

The controller calls a service `ServiceA`, that eventually calls another service `ServiceB`, and that service calls `userRepository.findUserById(userId)`.

But this call throws an Exception:

> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table "user" not found
> Table "person" not found; SQL statement: insert into user (created_at,
> user_field1, user_field2, user_field3) values (?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-200]
> could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into user (created_at,
> user_field1, user_field2, user_field3)values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested
> exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not
> prepare statement

Why is that ? The test method is annotated as `@Transactional`. I tried to add `@Transactional` to the method of `ServiceB` that calls the repository, but same error.

Answer (score 0):

> and that service calls userRepository.**findUserById**(userId).
>
> **But this call throws an Exception:**
>
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : Table "user" not found Table
> "person" not found; SQL statement: **insert into user** (created_at,
> user_field1, user_field2, user_field3) values (?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-200]
> could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into user (created_at,
> user_field1, user_field2, user_field3)values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested
> exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not
> prepare statement

Your question is not correct. The error does not popup from `userRepository.findUserById(userId)` sinse this would not trigger an insert sql query. Probably a `userRepository.save` is triggering this error.

Check if and how your entities and repositories are scanned for your database to be configured correctly.

Comment: I checked again, and this is indeed what happens. userRepository.findUserById(userId) triggers that insertion error. I don't know why, but it's what happens. I think something is off in the transaction management of that integration test...